# Are there now 64-bit processors that deal with denorms routinely with no exception or interrupt?

Tags: cpu, floating-point

Title says it all.

Are there processors with FPUs that deal with denorms arithmetically correctly (don't assume they're zero nor flush them to zero) and don't cause an exception? I would be interested in knowing who the black sheep and the white sheep are.  Like the Intel Xeon or AMD Opteron, are denorms for them just any old 64-bit floating-point number?

My app interest is about real-time digital signal processing.

Comment: My goodness this gotta lotta attention.